# Create a SharePoint sharelink with expiration and password using C# CSOM API

Tags: csom

From the SharePoint UI, you can share a document by providing an expiration date for the link and also securing that link using set password. Can the same be achieved from C# code using CSOM libraries?

Thanks,
Subhash

Comment: Could you also use GraphApi? If so this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) should help

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use Graph APIs.